# What is the .gitignore pattern equivalent of the regex (Big|Small)(State|City)-[0-9]*\.csv

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards, git, patterns

I have a regex I stuck in my `.gitignore` similar to:

```
(Big|Small)(State|City)-[0-9]*\.csv
```

It didn't work so I tested it against [RegexLab.NET](http://regexlab.codeplex.com/).

I then found the [gitignore](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore) man page which led me to learn that gitignore doesn't use regexes, but rather [fnmatch(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch).

However, fnmatch it doesn't seem to have an equivalent of the capture groups. Is this feasible or do I need to break this into three lines?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's no way to express this regular expression with the patterns that gitignore supports. The problem is not the lack of capture groups (in fact, you are not using capture groups as such), the problem is the lack of a `|` operator. You need to break this into four lines.

```
BigState-[0-9]*.csv
SmallState-[0-9]*.csv
BigCity-[0-9]*.csv
SmallCity-[0-9]*.csv
```

Note that the patterns match e.g. `BigState-4foo.csv`, since `*` matches any sequence of characters. You can't do better than this with glob patterns, unless you're willing to match only a fixed number of digits.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly what you said. Also, thanks for pointing out * does not repeat the previous expression, but is a while card. Its good enough for my needs, but I was hoping for better.